# How to correctly do SQL UPDATE with weighted subselect?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am probably trying to accomplish too much in a single query, but have I an sqlite database with badly formatted recipes. This returns a sorted list of recipes with relevance added:

```
SELECT *, sum(relevance) FROM (
  SELECT *,1 AS relevance FROM recipes WHERE ingredients LIKE '%milk%' UNION ALL
  SELECT *,1 AS relevance FROM recipes WHERE ingredients LIKE '%flour%' UNION ALL
  SELECT *,1 AS relevance FROM recipes WHERE ingredients LIKE '%sugar%'
) results GROUP BY recipeID ORDER BY sum(relevance) DESC;
```

But I'm now stuck with a special case where I need to write the relevance value to a field on the same row as the recipe. I figured something along these lines:

```
UPDATE recipes SET relevance=(SELECT sum(relevance) ...)
```

But I have not been able to get this working yet. I will keep trying, but meanwhile please let me know how you would approach this?

Edit: Evaluating Peter's solution, I ran into some serious performance issues, due to the amount of data the operations had to be performed on. I wrote a little Rebol script that does the loops and and the finding and does commits in 1000-row batches. It completed in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should get your model fixed (see below).

If you can't, the following query should work (I tried it and it worked as I expected).

```
Update recipes
Set relevance =
(
  Select   Case When ingredients Like '%milk%' Then 1 Else 0 End
         + Case When ingredients Like '%flour%' Then 1 Else 0 End
         + ...
  From recipes r2
  Where r2.recipe_id = recipes.recipe_id
)
```

It uses `Case` to sum up all matched ingredients.

---

**Suggested model:**

- Table `recipes`
- Table `ingredients`
- Table `recipe_ingredients`

  - `recipe_id`
  - `ingredient_id`

Comment: I agree, but it's much too broken to begin with. It seems basically a html scrape and I don't have the regexp-fu to divide the ingredients properly. Luckily, if I can get the relevance thing sorted, I won't have to touch it any more.. :)

Comment: @luminarious: Well, then make sure to try the query I provided :)

Comment: Does the syntax imply automatic summing, or you just missed the `SUM` invokation?

Comment: @newtover: That's what adding (`+`) the separate `Case` clauses is for. Every ingredient that is matched results in `1`, and I'm summing all those up. I do not group any rows here, so `SUM` would not work.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed that all ingridients for the recipe are stored in a single row.